# How to catch errors if IMongoCollection<T>.InsertOneAsync(...) returns no value nor throws any exception (according to documentation)?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Since `IMongoCollection<T>.InsertOneAsync(...)` returns no value (except the `awaitable` `Task`), and [its documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_InsertOneAsync.htm) says nothing about exceptions, how can I be sure that the new record was added and no error has happened?

```
IMongoCollection<RecordType> batch = recordsBatchFactory.Create();
RecordType newRecord = makeNewRecord();
await batch.InsertOneAsync(newRecord);
// is newRecord guaranteed to be in the DB at this point?
```

Comment: have a look : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an exception happens within the task it should cause the task to return faulted, see [Task<>.IsFaulted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted(v=vs.110).aspx).

However the exception should bubble up and be raised as an `AggregateException`.

Comment: I'm just confused, why doesn't the documentation say anything about exceptions...